# Can enctype="multipart/form-data" be used for non file inputs as well?

Tags: php, html, forms

Is this allowed?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="text_input" />
  <input type="other_types" name="other_types_input" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
  <input name="userfile" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

It will be used with PHP...

Comment: It's forbidden by Interstellar Internet Police and any act of using multipart/form-data will result in death sentence. :)

Comment: Lol... I have not tried it. Yep I am kinda being lazy after a few attempts at asking google with no results :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely correct. No issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine.

It's how forms with file elements in them are normally structured.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is old, the answers already posted has no explanation, so I am adding this, so that it will be helpful for future readers.

The HTTP POST method sends data to the server. The type of the body of the request is indicated by the Content-Type header.
The content type is selected by putting the adequate string in the enctype attribute of the  element or the formenctype attribute of the  or  elements.
HTML forms provide three methods of encoding.

1. application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default)
2. multipart/form-data
3. text/plain

for multipart/form-data, each value is sent as a block of data ("body part"), with a user agent-defined delimiter ("boundary") separating each part. The keys are given in the Content-Disposition header of each part. It does not matter if you are sending file or not. so it should be fine.

Refer [mozila doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)